# python - filtering with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A table like the one below has multiple incoming values for each existing row. How can I show the ones with zero values without listing them?

[image: I do not want to buy those whose value is zero]

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(klines, columns=labels)
 candles_df = pd.DataFrame(klines, columns=['T', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close'])
 morning_star = talib.CDLMORNINGSTAR(candles_df['open'], candles_df['high'], candles_df['low'],
                                candles_df['close'], penetration=0)
 engulfing = talib.CDLENGULFING(candles_df['open'], candles_df['high'], candles_df['low'], candles_df['close'])


 print(candles_df != 0)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "show without listing". Could you show the output you would want corresponding to the example input? I also don't understand what you mean by "incoming values".

Comment: so,
I don't want those with zero value. For example; Engulfing don't be on the list if it's 0

Comment: Try `candles_df.loc[ (candles_df['MorningStar'] != 0) | (candles_df['Engulfing'] != 0) ]`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`df.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter the boolean conditions, like below:

```
print(candles_df.loc[ (candles_df['MorningStar'] != 0) | (candles_df['Engulfing'] != 0) ])
```

The column names are based on your screen capture.

Here we filter to show only either

1. candles_df['MorningStar'] != 0
2. candles_df['Engulfing'] != 0

If both are zero, the boolean condition fails and would not be shown.